# Can I use the result of a comparison as an integer in C++?

Tags: c++, types, casting, comparison

Can I directly use a comparison as an integer in C++?

For example, can I do this?

```
int var = 0;
for (i=0;i<20;i++){
    var += (int)(var < 10);
}
```

In theory, this will increase *var* up to a value of 10.
I know that it works in Python.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you try before you ask?

Comment: Because it's easier to ask than to compile code!

Comment: Just to make the code more readable, I suggest using `var += (var < 10);`.

Comment: @uzumaki, for most people, it is easier to try that simple piece of code than asking a question at SO.

Comment: @uzumaki if you're not willing to put in any effort, why should anyone else?

Comment: @RSahu The code will work but they won't necessarily understand why.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, that was my response to the OP's comment that *it's eaasier to ask than to compile code*.

Comment: You can also write `if (var < 10) ++var;` and nobody has to ask if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, C++ has implicit casting from `bool` to `int`.

However, I would suggest you make this a bit more clear that this is your actual intention, so that future readers understand your intent. Explicitly cast it to an int first.

```
int var = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var += (int)(var < 10);
}
```

Comment: why not make it even more explicit and use an if statement?

Comment: It can potentially be slower. An if statement is a potential branching code point. Modern processors may attempt branch prediction. Simply explicitly casting the intended type will produce the same compiled code as the implicit cast, however.

Of course, it's an absolutely minimal optimization. If your audience would better understand your code with a few extra if statements, I'd always go for the more readable/understandable code.

Comment: In this case, it seems the if statement is faster since the compiler can know to abandon the loop when var becomes greater than 10.   https://godbolt.org/g/PZ1jDn  In the code as written in the answer, it always performs 20 iterations.